# What is the best approach in inter process communication?

Tags: .net, ipc, message-queue, named-pipes

Hi I am going to develop application in .net. It is .net core. It is web application. I have one process running on the same machine. This is written in c programming. I want to have bidirectional communication between my .net application and process. So which mechanism is well suited? requirements like i will be hosting my .net application in linux environment and process is also running in linux environment. I have gone through named pipes,message queues etc. So as per my requirement which will be the good solution? can someone help me in this regard? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on non functional requirements / performance requirements, but I recommend you go for a rest API.

I also recommend you consider a microservice architecture, as described https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-inter-process-communication/

Comment: Thank you jo writters. In .net i have chosen rest API with .net core 2.0. I will be hosting my .net code in nginx server. My .net code will e in ubuntu operating system. Also server(written in c programe) will be in same ubuntu operating system!

Comment: I have gone through the link you shared above. As i am using Rest API(client) and i want to make two way communication between client and server. So which would be the efficient IPC mechanism?

Comment: I recommend you go through this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613841/most-efficient-way-to-communicate-between-multiple-net-apps. It's pretty much the same topic, with lots of feedback on particular topics such as IPC and rest.